# Run a PHP function on document ready?

Tags: javascript, php

Is there anyway for me to run a certain php function when the document loads completely? I am trying to run a function which will mark a notification as read only when the document has been loaded completely. What can I do?

Comment: Reconsider your logic or just use `ajax` or load an `IMG` in `JS` `onLoad`. PHP is long finished building your page's HTML when your document ready gets triggered. You need to callback to achieve the result you seek.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can detect the "document-ready" event with a Javascript script and when that is triggered, perform an AJAX request to a PHP page that will run the script you need.

With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) it gets as simple as using [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do an ajax call to that php file on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

You must use AJAX for this, php is done server side so AJAX is the only way :)